# Hausdorff dimension of a ball

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

> Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_m\}$ be an IFs and $E_n$ be the associated self similar set. It's known that $E_n$ is a union of disjoint balls $B(x_i,R\cdot r^n)$ (balls with same radius but not the same center). Find $\dim_HE_n.$

I thought using the fact that it's a union of disjoint balls saying $$\dim_HE_n=\sup\dim_HB_{n,i}$$(where $B_{n,i}$ is the ball which is associated with $f_i$)$$=\dim_HB(x,R\cdot r^n)=Rr^n\dim_HB(0,1)$$From here it seems like the dimension of the unit ball is 1 but I'm not sure since I know nothing about $E_n$ and it can also a non-euclidean space. How can I find the Hausdorff dimension of the unit ball?

**EDIT**: The original question was [image] About part A I said that each ball can be moved in each direction distance of $R\cdot r^n$ "positve and negative" (in the intuition of euclidean space) and thus we would get a bounding with $L(n)$ to the Malinowski dimension. Now I'm stuck at part b. afterwards I'll have to understand how can I solve c.

Comment: IFs = Iterated Function System? And what is knwon about the $f_i$ (linear, continuous, ...?)

Comment: indeed. oh, I forgot $\forall 1\le i \le n:f_i$ is a similitude with contraction ratio $r^n$

Comment: In that case and if $E_n=\bigcup f_i(E_n)$ I doubt that $E_n$ can be the union of disjoint balls.

Comment: So there are $n$ maps in the IFS, but they also have contraction ratio $r^n$, the same $n$?

Comment: I posted the full question. and yes.

Comment: The Hausdorff dimension of a ball is equal to the algebraic dimension of the ambient vector space (i.e., it is $d$ in $\mathbb R^d$). This is not helpful here.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^d$,, that's indeed correct but I'm looking for a solution for a general space.